# How to deploy angular2 cli app on github?

Tags: angular, typescript, deployment, angular-cli

I am front and engineer and have no experience with deploying.

I am developing my pet project using angular-cli.

How can I deploy it on github pages?

There is another simple way to do this?

Comment: Google is your friend: http://shermandigital.com/blog/deploy-an-angular-cli-application-to-github-pages/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow the angular-cli Wiki stories which can be found [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories).

The one you're looking for is [Deploy to GitHub Pages](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-github-pages).

> A simple way to deploy your Angular app is to use GitHub Pages.
>
> The first step is to create a GitHub account, and then create a
>   repository for your project. Make a note of the user name and project
>   name in GitHub.
>
> Then all you need to do is run ng build --prod --output-path docs
>   --base-href PROJECT_NAME, where PROJECT_NAME is the name of your project in GitHub. Make a copy of docs/index.html and name it
>   docs/404.html.
>
> Commit your changes and push. On the GitHub project page, configure it
>   to publish from the docs folder.
>
> And that's all you need to do! Now you can see your page at
>   https://USER_NAME.github.io/PROJECT_NAME/.
>
> You can also use angular-clip-ghpages, a full featured package that
>   does this all this for you and has extra functionality.